# How can I stop a radio streaming with sonos cloud api?

Tags: sonos

I developing a new application to control Sonos speakers with New Sonos Cloud API and in the documentation, there is nothing to stop the radio stations when it's playing. the API return can pause == false but there is a stop possible? If yes how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just calling pause? https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playback/pause

Comment: Yes and this does not work. I precise that canPause is false.

Comment: Pause will work. the canPause flag is actually getting pretty specific: it indicates that this content can't be paused and picked back up later. This makes sense, as you can't stop, for instance, a live station and pick it up where you left off later.

Comment: I confirm this works. Thank you! But canPause should only be used to show a pause or a stop button? Do you confirm we can always call pause action regardless of canPause value?

Comment: In the LAN api there is also a canStop state, but Cloud doesn't offer that. canPause and canStop will not be available when nothing is playing, for example.